# Use of is/are in a sentence with list

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement

*Her compassion and devotion is/are second to none.*

I'm guessing "is" since "Her" is singular?

"Are" just sounds better.

Comment: After 'bread and butter' we use IS. The user should decide whether 'compassion and devotion' is so close as 'bread and butter'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **are** because the subject is plural -- compassion and devotion are two separate things, not a single thing.